# ¿Qué error estoy cometiendo al usuar ngSwitch?

Tags: angular

Tengo un proyecto nuevo de Angular donde hay un módulo llamado "Songs" y un componente llamado "level". Lo que pasa es que estoy intentando usar un ngSwitch en este componente pero me da el error "Can't bind to 'ngSwitch' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.". Lo que pasa es que yo sé que este error se da cuando no está incluído el CommonModule en el módulo donde está el componente, entonces lo agregué pero aún así me sigue dando el error.
Mi level.component.html se ve así:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="level">
    <div class="levelContainer" *ngSwitchCase="0">
        <img src="../../../../assets/Songs/level-easy.svg" alt="" class="levelImg">
        <p class="levelText">Principiante</p>
    </div>
    <div class="levelContainer" *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <img src="../../../../assets/Songs/level-medium.svg" alt="" class="levelImg">
        <p class="levelText">Intermedio</p>
    </div>
    <div class="levelContainer" *ngSwitchCase="2">
        <img src="../../../../assets/Songs/level-hard.svg" alt="" class="levelImg">
        <p class="levelText">Avanzado</p>
    </div>
    <div class="levelContainer" *ngSwitchDefault>
        <img src="../../../../assets/Songs/level-easy.svg" alt="" class="levelImg">
        <p class="levelText">Principiante</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Mi level.component.ts se ve así:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-level',
  templateUrl: './level.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./level.component.scss']
})
export class LevelComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() level:number = 0;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Mi songs.module.ts se ve así:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { TitleComponent } from './components/title/title.component';
import { LevelComponent } from './components/level/level.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TitleComponent,
    LevelComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TitleComponent,
  ]
})
export class SongsModule { }
```

Y por último mi app.module.ts se ve así:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de qué error estoy cometiendo?

Comment: Utilice el código sobre un proyecto de prueba y no me dio errores, probaste finalizando y volviendo a lanzar el proyecto?

Comment: Si lo he probado, por alguna razón aún no logro hacer que funcione. En otros proyectos usar el código de esta manera me ha funcionado, sin embargo acá no. Es posible que me falte configurar/instalar algo?

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si cambias las imágenes por texto? A lo mejor y existe un problema ahí.

Comment: Hace un rato descubrí que el error era que no estaba importando el songs module en app.module. Una vez hice eso empezó a server angular material y directivas como el ngSwitch. Gracias por la ayuda de todos modos!